# Extracting the sheet name from an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I have defined an array with two variables: the name of the sheet and the pagesetup.printarea.

```
varArray(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & " " & Worksheets(i).PageSetup.PrintArea
```

The problem is that the sheetname includes a number, which I do not need (e.g., `China2`). How can I extract just the string part of the sheetname and the printarea separately? Or, is there an better way to set this up to begin with? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's is better way. You can use `Dictionary` class, but you have to provide more details about your issue.

Comment: The number of sheets can vary. So, I set up an array to capture the data that I need: the name of each sheet and the print ranges that are set on each sheet. The sheet names (for whatever reason) contain a number. For example, one sheet name is China2. All I need is "China" and the print range, but as two different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand your curent approach and use a 2D array.

Which IMO is better suited that a dictionary in that you can expand the number of elements if required and as the critical reason to use a dictionary (multiple occurences) is absent.

Also uses a `regexp` to clean, but takes out all digits.

```
Sub Test()
Dim x() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lngCnt As Long

ReDim x(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count, 1 To 2)

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
    x(lngCnt, 1) = CleanStr(ws.Name)
    x(lngCnt, 2) = ws.PageSetup.PrintArea
Next

End Sub
```

*optional cleaning function*

```
Function CleanStr(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
   .Pattern = "\d+"
   .Global = True
   CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

As i mentioned in comment, there's a better way to store sheet names and print areas. It's called [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). For example:

```
'needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim dic As Dictionary

Set dic = New Dictionary
dic.Add "SheetName", "PrintArea"


'get print area for sheet
Dim sPrintArea As String
sPrintArea = dic("SheetName")
```

As you can see, now you can access to the print area via sheet name ;)

If you want to enumerate all keys and values, use `for...each` loop:

```
Dim oKey As Variant
For Each oKey In dic.Keys
 MsgBox oKey & vbTab & dic(oKey)
Next
```

If you want to get only `China`, you may use [Regex within Excel](http://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/):

```
'needs reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x
Dim oRegex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

Set oRegex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

sPattern = "\d{1,}"
With oRegex
    .Pattern = sPattern
    .MultiLine = False
End With
sPureSheetName = oRegex.Replace(sSheetName, "")
```

Comment: Sorry, I am relatively new to VBA and I have not used the Dictionary class before. Once this is set up and run, how can I extract the name and printarea for each sheet from dic? I will need this information later as I need to create a pdf for each sheet and save it as its sheet name.

Comment: Please, read my answer carefully. There's everything what you need ;)

Comment: How will `"\d{1,}"` capture `China`?

Comment: So, do I need to dic.add each sheet name and print area manually? There are usually 20+ sheets. As I said, I am relatively new to VBA and I just simply do not understand.

Comment: @MacroMan, this pattern will capture number (one or more). It is necessary to remove number from string ;)

Comment: @ectrimm, yes. You can do that when workbook is opened (use `Workbook_Open` event).

Comment: @MaciejLos aaaaahh - I see, sorry I thought you were using that pattern to actually _find_ China lol didn't pay attention to the `Replace` method at the end!

Comment: @MacroMan. Don't worry. ;) Cheers, Maciej

Comment: But the names and print ranges may change.

Comment: But I was trying to take the "manual" out of the process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ectrimm. You're ery welcome. I'm not sure i understand what you're trying to achieve. I showed you up the way how to store the names and print areas using dictionary object. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: @MaciejLos OP just wanted to be spoon fed XD Good answer.

Comment: Okay, it took me a minute. I got it to work. Thanks again.